# NavigationView has dark bar at bottom

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have drawer implemented in my app which is limited items.
But i can see some dark bar at the bottom.

Here is the code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#252525"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemTextColor="#a4a4a4"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

activity_main_drawer.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_profile"
            android:title="Profile"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_history"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_history"
            android:title="History" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_help"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_help"
            android:title="Help" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_setting"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_settings"
            android:title="Settings"/>
</menu>
```

Already tried android:fitsSystemWindows="true" for parent and child and alone. No use of it. Can any one help, how to solve this issue.

I am attaching the screenshot

[image]

Comment: can you post menu activity_main_drawer.xml as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

step 1:update this code in activity_main.xml (add `app:insetForeground="@null"`)

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:insetForeground="@null"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

step 2: just place this code in Mainactivity

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Comment: thank you so much i added that line in mainactivity and 1 extra line in xml app:insetForeground="@null". it worked :)